# How to calibrate ToF(Time-of-Flight) camera or Lidar with RGB camera

Tags: opencv, point-cloud-library, openni, lidar

I am trying to get depth of each pixel from RGB camera.

So I use ToF camera and Lidar(SICK) to get depth data through [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) and [OpenNI](http://openni.ru/index.html).

In order to project the depth data to RGB image currectly, I need to known the Rotation and translation (so-called pose) of ToF or Lidar to the RGB camera.

[OpenCV module](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) provide the stereo calibration to get pose between two RGB camera.

But I can not use same way because of that depth sensor only get depth data so that corner detecton of chessboard for calibration will fail.

So...what sould I do if I want to get depth of each pixel from RGB camera.

thanks for any suggestion~~

Comment: http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration

Comment: thanks @Micka.  I also find this [paper](https://sites.google.com/site/jyjungcv/tof_calibration) about this kind of calibration.


I have few question:
1. will the depth camera intrinsics not reliable just with 4  corners of the chessboard.



2. step "Stereo calibration" use the 4  corners of the chessboard from color and depth image to get homography matrix and the get RT matrix right ?


3. is it possible to do backward mapping?  from color image to depth. if I want to known the depth of each pixel in color image.

Comment: yes you are right, to get the instrinsics of the depth sensor you might need more points. You could try to create a depth pattern, where the chessboard fields have some "height". Tp move from color image to depth image maybe you can just invert the transform. Sorry, no time to check this.

Comment: Hi @Micka If I get homography matrix from corners of the chessboard from color and depth image in image coordinate (pixel) 
will it still work that I mapping depth image (in in meters) to color image (pixel)? 
Because I don't known how to get intrinsics in meters, I don't have mmpp (millimeter per pixel) and sensor size.

Or I can use point from color (in pixel) and depth (in in meters) to get the homography and RT matrix to avoid this issue?

Comment: I guess the homography will be scaled to overcome this issue, but no guarantee from me, just try it. Or calibrate the color cam to get the intrinsics.